# Spring compatible scrypt password with python passlib

Tags: java, python, spring, scrypt, passlib

How can I generate Spring compatible passwords from python?

I've got a spring application creating scrypt passwords that look like this in the db:

> {scrypt}$e0801$QAqC0fvhY6iJPysiQsFnrcUg205njHo/6o+IDXDn33lxmZOCVBhb4NAqdafhuGmykCxQtMI5xP5zb7MYMUrU3Q==$sBeXCHOm6zQuGdSDKs+HeXnNQGg3bhRidmL+HU/ZTMM=

I'm trying to update the database directly with new passwords using python and passlib but cannot divine the correct setting_kwds for passlib from `$e0801$`:

```py
>>> from passlib.hash import scrypt
>>> scrypt.verify('wBkfoBsxj9u3wLOZ', '{scrypt}$e0801$QAqC0fvhY6iJPysiQsFnrcUg205njHo/6o+IDXDn33lxmZOCVBhb4NAqdafhuGmykCxQtMI5xP5zb7MYMUrU3Q==$sBeXCHOm6zQuGdSDKs+HeXnNQGg3bhRidmL+HU/ZTMM=')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gregn/.pyenv/versions/v2.7.16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 789, in verify
    self = cls.from_string(hash, **context)
  File "/home/gregn/.pyenv/versions/v2.7.16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/passlib/handlers/scrypt.py", line 177, in from_string
    return cls(**cls.parse(hash))
  File "/home/gregn/.pyenv/versions/v2.7.16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/passlib/handlers/scrypt.py", line 181, in parse
    ident, suffix = cls._parse_ident(hash)
  File "/home/gregn/.pyenv/versions/v2.7.16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 1207, in _parse_ident
    raise exc.InvalidHashError(cls)
ValueError: not a valid scrypt hash
```

Manually fiddling with the prefix format hasn't worked:

```py
>>> scrypt.verify('wBkfoBsxj9u3wLOZ', '$scrypt$ln=1,r=8,p=1$QAqC0fvhY6iJPysiQsFnrcUg205njHo/6o+IDXDn33lxmZOCVBhb4NAqdafhuGmykCxQtMI5xP5zb7MYMUrU3Q==$sBeXCHOm6zQuGdSDKs+HeXnNQGg3bhRidmL+HU/ZTMM=')
False
```

I think ( but am not certain) Spring is using default SCryptPasswordEncoder settings because I found:

```java
public static PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    final String encodingId = "scrypt";
    final Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
    encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    encoders.put(encodingId, new SCryptPasswordEncoder());
    return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(encodingId, encoders);
}
```

spring version:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.18.RELEASE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The one you provided is not a valid scrypt hash

```
{scrypt}$e0801$QAqC0fvhY....
```

This is the right format (just substitute `{scrypt}` with `$s0`)

```
$s0$e0801$QAqC0fvhY6iJPysiQsFnrcUg205njHo/6o+IDXDn33lxmZOCVBhb4NAqdafhuGmykCxQtMI5xP5zb7MYMUrU3Q==$sBeXCHOm6zQuGdSDKs+HeXnNQGg3bhRidmL+HU/ZTMM=
```

If you try to get the configurations with [Password4j](https://github.com/Password4j/password4j):

```
SCryptFunction.getInstanceFromHash("$s0$e0801$QAqC0...");
```

you get `N=16384`, `r=8` and `p=1`. Use this configuration in your Python implementation.